# Matlab Color Quantization

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, k-means, quantization

I'm currently working on project which is related with color quantization.The algorithm implies as initial step k-means algorithm . My code untill now :

```
N = 10;
K=7;
I=imread('baboon.bmp');
Idouble = double(I);
mat=zeros(size(I,1)*size(I,2),size(I,3));
R=I(:,:,1);
G=I(:,:,2);
B=I(:,:,3);

mat(:,1)=R(:);
mat(:,2)=G(:);
mat(:,3)=B(:);
[IDX,CENTERS] = kmeans(mat,N);
```

Next step in the algorithm is finding the most popular color(the color which contains the most pixels in the image) . It seems very easy but somewhat I get stuck when I tried to extract that from `IDX` variable .

Comment: The variable `Idouble` is useless. Plus you can merge the last 8 lines in one with `squeeze` and concatenation. Then, I don't understand your question: what is the desired output ? Why do you need kmeans ? Isn't `unique (...,.'rows)` enough ?

Comment: `IDX` should contain the index of the cluster `[1..k]` for each point in `mat`. So `sum(IDX==1)` should give you the number of points in cluster 1, right?

Comment: @beaker yes..you're right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kmeans` returns the centroids / representative colours that exist in your image stored in `CENTERS` and `IDX` gives you the membership of each pixel.  Each row of `CENTERS` is a centroid and with that, `IDX` tells you which row from `CENTERS` you would need to reference that a pixel in your image got assigned to after the clustering.

If you want to find the "most popular colour", I'm assuming you mean the most **frequently occurring**.  In that case, apply a [`mode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mode.html) operation to your cluster membership vector, then use this to index into `CENTERS` to get the most popular cluster:

```
idx_popular = mode(IDX);
popular_colour = CENTERS(idx_popular,:);
```

---

## Minor Note

As `kmeans` is a randomized algorithm, it is highly probable that your cluster centroids will be different at each iteration - whether they're different all together or the same but in a different order is subject to the algorithm.

I would suggest you run the `kmeans` algorithm a few times to ensure that you do get the most popular colour with high probability.  That can be done by specifying the `Replicates` flag when running `kmeans`:

```
num_repeats = 5; %// For example
[IDX,CENTERS] = kmeans(mat, N, 'Replicates', num_repeats);
```

Comment: thank you . I also came across with other solution but this one seems more elegant and definitely faster .

Comment: @AlbertoCarp - No problem at all.  I'm glad I interpreted the problem correctly. Good luck!